# Customising Devise registration edit/update routes and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've just started using Devise and I've made some customisations:

- I've generated views and customised my views (signup form etc)
- I've generated controllers so I can make some changes there
- I've customised routes, mostly as per this post: http://iampedantic.com/post/41170460234/fully-customizing-devise-routes

Everything works great except the edit_user_registration stuff (the view where users can change their email and password or delete their account).

This is what I have for registrations in `config/routes.rb` (parts not related to registrations controller are omitted):

```
devise_for  :users, skip: [:registrations]

as :user do

  # joining
  get   '/register' => 'users/registrations#new', as: 'new_user_registration'
  post  '/register' => 'users/registrations#create', as: 'user_registration'

  scope '/user' do

  # settings & cancellation
  get '/cancel'   => 'users/registrations#cancel', as: 'cancel_user_registration'
  get '/settings' => 'users/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
  patch '/settings' => 'users/registrations#update'

  # account deletion
  delete '' => 'users/registrations#destroy'

end
```

I changed `put` to `patch` because I'm using Rails 4 (is this correct?).

This is my form_for tag in `views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(resource,  as: resource_name,
                            url: registration_path(resource_name),
                            html: { method: :patch }) do |f| %>
```

When I try to update settings for a user with the above code, I get a 500 internal server error. Submitting the form attempts to load `/register` (my signup page), which is surely not right. *(I think this is the heart of the problem but I don't understand how to fix it as I'm quite a beginner.)*

When I try to update settings for a user with the original `put` method (instead of `patch`), I get the same problem.

My development web server says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/register"):
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added `rake routes` output below.

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
   new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)             users/registrations#new
       user_registration POST   /register(.:format)             users/registrations#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /user/cancel(.:format)          users/registrations#cancel
  edit_user_registration GET    /user/settings(.:format)        users/registrations#edit
                settings PUT    /user/settings(.:format)        users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /user(.:format)                 users/registrations#destroy
```

EDIT 2: This is what `rakes routes` looks like when I remove custom routes and let Devise handle registrations views etc.:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
```

WORKING:

**routes.rb**:

```
get 'settings'  => 'users/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
put 'settings/:id' => 'users/registrations#update', as: 'update_user_registration'
```

**edit.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for(resource,  as: resource_name,
                        url: update_user_registration_path(resource_name),
                        html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Please post the `rake routes` output.

Comment: Ok @Pavan, please see above.

Comment: Try changing url as `settings_path(resource_name)`

Comment: @Pavan I tried that and it raises the following:
`ActionController::UnknownFormat in Users::RegistrationsController#update`
The URL it tries to load is `http://localhost:3000/user/settings.user`

Comment: I've added another set of rake routes above. Comparing the two, there's an extra route in Devise's own set so I guess I need to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `registration_path` is submitting the form to `/register`, which is for new users, but you're trying to edit an existing `User` object, so you need to submit to the correct update path. By default, that's the `PUT /users/:id` you see when you remove your configurations.

It looks like your customizations have set the `User` update path to `PUT /user/settings`, so try `url: settings_path`. You're aiming for the `users/registrations#update` action seen in this row:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
          settings PUT    /user/settings(.:format)        users/registrations#update
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'll add the working code above.

Comment: Thanks for the working code - I was wondering if you'd need `/:id` or if the controller was inferring it from the logged-in user.